# "IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory" when it is a file

Tags: python, file-rename

I tried using:

```
import os
my_path = [files for pth, dirs, files in os.walk(path)]
result_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for original_path, new_name in zip(my_path, result_list):
    os.rename(original_path, 'path_to_save'.format(new_name))
```

where I get:

> `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'path-of-original-path' -> 'path-of-new-name'`

but I can confirm that 'original_path' leads to a file as on using `os.path.isfile` returns `True`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't imported `os`.

Comment: As well as `from os import path`.

Comment: did you use `print()` to display both paths? `original_path, new_name` may have something different than you expect.

Comment: @furas yes, i did. It had what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why but using this worked:

```
import shutil
shutil.move(original_path, 'path_to_save'.format(new_name))
```